# How to select a value from drop down based on the value given from Excel sheet using selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am currently learning to automate a web application which contains drop down.The thing is am able to select the the value from drop down by giving it directly in the xpath.Now i am trying to select a value from drop down based on the value given in the excel sheet rather than giving it directly.I dont know how to go about it .

Please find the sample HTML

```
<select class="parent" id="parent_name" name="parentId">                                      
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
  </select>
```

Please find the code i tried for drop down

```
dropdown=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="parent"]//option[2]');
dropdown.click();
```

For selecting the value from excel for others thing like text box i am using the below code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome  
driver.fullscreen_window();
driver.get('url');
time.sleep(5) 
Workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("excel path")
Details = Workbook.sheet_by_index(0);
city=Details .cell(1,0)
Citytextbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="city"]');
Citytextbox.send_keys(city.value);
```

What i am expecting is if i give value as "A" in excel,it should be able to select it from drop down rather than hard coding it
am using spyder-python 3.7.

**Update** :Tried following two methods i facing the below issue .can you guide me on what the issue might be.
The first method ,it seems noting is happening,code is running even with selecting the drop down and no error is shows.It seems it didn't come into code

```
 class test:
        def test(self):
           type=details.cell(1,13);
    dropdown=selected(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="parent"]')); 
               dropdown.select_by_value(str(type));
               time.sleep(5);
```

**Second method** :It it shows -module' object is not callable.Added import select as selected

```
type=details.cell(1,13);
dropdown=selected(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="parent"]'));
dropdown.select_by_value(str(type));
```

When i try it by the above method i am getting this error
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [Select object](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html).  First of all pull the relevant value out of your Excel document (you'll need to tweak the below to target the relevant cell, I've provided an example based on your question):

```
Workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("excel path")
Details = Workbook.sheet_by_index(0);
selectValue = Details .cell(1,0)
```

Then you will need to use the value as shown below:

```
select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("parent_name")) 
select.select_by_value(str(selectValue))
```

Comment: I have tried two methods based what you have provide ,am facing issues.Can you guide me on that.i haveUpdate what i tried in question it self

Comment: The code for your "second method" that you have added to your question does not match the code above.

Comment: since the first one didn't work.i changed code by removing the class ,def ,self function.since i dint know what the issue was

Comment: You have used `selected` not `Select`.  case sensitivity and spelling accuracy matters to Python.

Comment: After modifying the code to select  also it does not work.It doesnt throw any issue .The code is just running

Comment: In that case we will need more information.  Are you sure you are pulling data from Excel correctly.  Is there a value that matches the data being pulled from Excel.  Is there a mismatch because of additional whitespace somewhere.  Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode?